# Datagridcombobox value not displaying

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a DataGridView (called DataGridViewSecurity) in VB.net (Visual Studio 2010) which is bound to a DataTable (called DataTableSecurity) in a DataSet (called DataSetSecurity).  I have added a nonbound column (called nSecurityComboBox) that I set based on an integer field (called nSecLevel) in the DataTable.  After setting the combobox, it doesn't display anything in the combobox, but when you select the combobox, the 5 values in it's items collection show.

Here's the code I'm using to add a record to the DataTable and then to set the combobox:

```
Sub Foo()
.
.
.
    DataSetSecurity.Tables(0).Rows.Add(New Object() {sName, sID, sSec})
    ComboCell_Select(nRow, 3, DataGridViewSecurity, sSecRecs.nSecLevel)
    MessageBox.Show("Value for the combo set at " + DataGridViewSecurity.Rows(nRow).Cells(3).Value.ToString)
.
.
.
End Sub

Private Sub ComboCell_Select(ByVal dgvRow As Integer, _
                             ByVal dgvCol As Integer, _
                             ByRef DGV As DataGridView,
                             ByRef nComboBoxRow As Int16)

    Try
        Dim CBox As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = CType(DGV.Rows(dgvRow).Cells(dgvCol), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        Dim CCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(DGV.Columns(dgvCol), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)

        CBox.Value = CCol.Items(nComboBoxRow)
        DGV.UpdateCellValue(dgvCol, dgvRow)

        'MessageBox.Show("New value in the combo box = " + CBox.Value.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The messagebox.show in Foo shows the correct value for the combobox, but nothing is displayed.
Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

-NCGrimbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I found some C# code that I converted to VB.net to fix the issue.  Here's the code:

```
Private Sub DataGridViewSecurity_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewSecurity.EditingControlShowing
    Dim cellComboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
    If cellComboBox IsNot Nothing Then
        ' make sure the handler doen't get registered twice
        RemoveHandler cellComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted, AddressOf Me.CellComboBoxOnSelectionChangeCommitted
        AddHandler cellComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted, AddressOf Me.CellComboBoxOnSelectionChangeCommitted
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CellComboBoxOnSelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim comboBox As DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl = TryCast(sender, DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
    If sender Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    If comboBox.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    If Me.DataGridViewSecurity.CurrentCell.Value = comboBox.SelectedItem Then
        Return
    End If

    Me.DataGridViewSecurity.CurrentCell.Value = comboBox.SelectedItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but you need to  change your code line to this : 
`If CustDG.CurrentCell.Value Is comboBox.SelectedItem Then`
            `Return`
        `End If`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, all values are in the combobox just not being selected by default properly?  I think I just had this problem a few days ago, here's what I have now.

```
'Create the combobox column
Dim comboBox As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()

'Add some stuff to the combobox
comboBox.Items.Add("FirstItem")
comboBox.Items.Add("SecondItem")

'Select the first item
comboBox.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = comboBox.Items(0) 

'Now add the whole combobox to the DataGridView
dgvItems.Columns.Add(comboBox)
```

Hope this helps!